# Convert letters in a column of strings to numbers in R

Tags: r

I am trying to solve the following: here is the top of my df

```
  Col1    Col2
1 Basic    ABC
2     B   ABCD          
3     B    abc
4     B   ab c
5     B   AB12
```

Col2 is a string column. I now want to convert the strings to unique numbers, based on the specific words

Like this:

```
  Col1    Col2       Col3
1 Basic    ABC        123
2     B   ABCD       1234          
3     B    abc     272829
4     B   ab c    2728029
5     B   AB12       1212
...
```

As you see, there can be CAPITAL LETTERS, numbers, lower cases, and spaces, that need to be converted to a specific numeric value. It doesn't matter, what numbers are generated, they only need to be unique.

The difficult part is, that I need static numeric IDs but my df is dynamic.
Meaning: Strings can be added or removed over time, but if i.e. the string "dog" is added - it gets an ID (i.e. "789") which was and will never be used by another string. So the generated IDs are not influenced by the col2 size, the position of strings in that column or any order - only by the content of a string itself.

Help is much appreciated

Comment: How does `abc` become `272829` ?

Comment: and presumably `BGBHBI` also becomes `272829`???

Comment: why not established `utf8ToInt` or `charToRaw`?

Comment: It sounds like you want sort of hashing function. There are a bunch of different types to choose from. Try searching for that term to see if you can find what you want.

Comment: `digest::digest2int("foobar")` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that number was only an example, but as Andrew Gustar pointed out, this system where every letter gets a number and than you just put them in a row is not working for my issue ... did not entirely thought that trough

Comment: @Maël Would have worked as well thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just mapping characters within some master vector, then perhaps this:

```r
chrs <- c(LETTERS, letters, 0:9)
quux$Col3 <- sapply(strsplit(quux$Col2, ""), function(z) paste(match(z, chrs, nomatch = 0L), collapse = ""))
quux
#    Col1 Col2    Col3
# 1 Basic  ABC     123
# 2     B ABCD    1234
# 3     B  abc  272829
# 4     B ab c 2728029
# 5     B AB12  125455
```

or a dplyr variant, if you're already using it (but this varies very little):

```r
library(dplyr)
quux %>%
  mutate(Col3 = sapply(strsplit(Col2, ""), function(z) paste(match(z, chrs, nomatch = 0L), collapse = "")))
#    Col1 Col2    Col3
# 1 Basic  ABC     123
# 2     B ABCD    1234
# 3     B  abc  272829
# 4     B ab c 2728029
# 5     B AB12  125455
```

However, as MrFlick suggested, perhaps what you really need is a hashing function?

```r
sapply(quux$Col2, digest::digest, algo = "sha256")
#                                                                ABC 
# "8fe32130ce14a3fb071473f9b718e403752f56c0f13081943d126ffb28a7b923" 
#                                                               ABCD 
# "942a0d444d8cf73354e5316517909d5f34b17963214a8f5b271375fe1da43013" 
#                                                                abc 
# "9f7b8da9f3abe2caaf5212f6b224448706de57b3c7b5dda916ee8d6005d9f24b" 
#                                                               ab c 
# "a3f1c49979af0fffa22f68028a42d302e0a675798ac4ac8a76bed392880af8f2" 
#                                                               AB12 
# "9ffbe9825833ab3c6b183f9986ab194a7aefcc06f5c940549a2c799dd4cd15b1"
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(Col1 = c("Basic", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Col2 = c("ABC", "ABCD", "abc", "ab c", "AB12")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Ah yeah, haven't thought about hashing functions. That's perfect!

Answer (score 2):

ah r2 beat me but same concept

```
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "a Col1    Col2
1 Basic    ABC
2     B   ABCD          
3     B    abc
4     B   'ab c'
5     B   AB12")

dd$Col2


f <- function(x) {
  x <- strsplit(x, '')
  sapply(x, function(y)
    factor(y, c(' ', LETTERS, letters, 0:9), c(0, 1:26, 27:52, 0:9)) |>
      as.character() |> paste0(`...` = _, collapse = ''))
}

f(dd$Col2)
# [1] "123"     "1234"    "272829"  "2728029" "1212"
```

Comment: The biggest difference (in my eye) is that I don't explicitly match a space, I assume anything non-letter/number is a `0`. Potentially an incorrect implementation on my part.